# Stylish pdf invoice build in .net

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf

I am writing code in .net to make an invoice. First I assign html code to a stringbuilder then pass that to a PDF converter. I am using inline css style `style='width: 100%;`,  page width tag works fine but when I use `font-family: 'Times New Roman';` it will not show on output PDF file. [image]
I want to add style fonts and images in output pdf file.

```
 protected void GenerateInvoicePDF(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<table style='width: 100%; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed; -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;'>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td>INVOICE #00007654345</td>");
                sb.Append("<tr><td colspan='2'></td></tr>");
                sb.Append("<td style='text-align: right;font-family: 'Times New Roman'; -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed; -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;'>Senor John<br />55th Road, CoolVill<br />654554 - ARR<br /><br />+1 123 4567 8910<br />e-mail</td>");
                sb.Append("</tr><tr><td colspan='2'></td></tr></table>");


                //Export HTML String as PDF.
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
                Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
                HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
                pdfDoc.Open();
                htmlparser.Parse(sr);
                pdfDoc.Close();
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Invoice_" + orderNo + ".pdf");
                Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

**BTW:** I'm first writing HTML page with `inline data` using HTMLWriter than convert it into pdf file is it possible that i amusing all html components i.e. bootstrap, images or styling in HTMLWriter.... ?
or just forget all these things and start using Crystal Reporting for the purpose of Invoice Making....?

Comment: I won't say don't try to do what your doing, but I've had good luck using PDFSharp http://www.pdfsharp.net/  or alternatively you can use the SQL Reporting feature in Visual Studio to build .RDLC templates.  Both ways are fairly robust in their capabilities.  The RDLC templates in SQL Reporting provide a little GUI where fonts and images can be set.

Comment: @tayler is it good idea to use `CrystalReporting` for invoices ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ending the attribute of `style` with the single quote at the beginning of `Times New Roman`.

notice how it is rendered if you look at it as just html

```
<table style='width: 100%; font-family: 'Times New Roman'; -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed; -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;'>
```

You need to use a double quote and escape it.

```
sb.Append("<table style='width: 100%; font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed; -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;'>");
```

this will render as

```
<table style='width: 100%; font-family: "Times New Roman"; -fs-pdf-font-embed: embed; -fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;'>
```

Comment: kindly tell me can i use inline styling in HTMLWriter that i am using using in C# or it just allow limited tags of HTML... ???